# How to redefine the simpleType having union?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xsd-1.1

I am having a doubt in redefining a simple type of one XSD in another XSD.

**sample1.xsd:**

```
  <xs:simpleType name="tLineType">
    <xs:union>
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:enumeration value="mainLine" />
          <xs:enumeration value="secondaryLine" />
          <xs:enumeration value="branchLine" />
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="tOtherEnumerationValue" />
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:union>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType name="tOtherEnumerationValue">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
     <xs:pattern value="other:\w{2,}" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

**sample2.xsd:**

I need to add some more enumeration values to the tLineType(ex:test_Track, Depot).

How to achieve the above functionality?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In xs:redefine, you can only redefine your schema by making it more restrictive, whereas you are trying to make it more liberal (by adding allowed values that were not allowed before).

You've tagged it XSD 1.1. In XSD 1.1 there is a new mechanism, xs:override, which allows arbitrary changes to components in the base schema.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to use XSD 1.0. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Define an XSLT transformation that modifies the base schema and run the validation against the modified schema.